# Electricians left breakers unhooked

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Handy homeowner here. Electricians ran wire and put in 5 new breakers on my panel as part of an addition to my house. One is hooked up and feeds an outlet, the other 4 are dead. Flipping the switches does nothing. They left something unhooked, but I don't know what it is. I'd like to take over and do the easy trim work (outlets, switches, fixtures) myself. I opened up the panel, but don't see anything obvious. Thoughts on how to liven up these breakers?

Comment: Do you know for sure that they're *supposed* to do anything?  They may have left them as spares for future use.  Sometimes a panel will come with more breakers than you need.

Comment: In the title you say "unhooked", in the description you day "dead". These are not necessarily the same thing, although IF a breaker was not plugged onto the bus, it is of course, "dead". So which is it? can you take a picture of the inside ofr ht panel and post it?

Comment: what does `liven up` mean?

Comment: has the exectricin claimed to have complered all the work?

Comment: Agreed, an amateur messing about with the unfinished work of a professional is a disaster waiting to happen. Ask the professional when he will be finishing and if he couldn't finish, ask him where he left the work.

Comment: Electricians have not claimed completion. I think they left all the neutrals unhooked in the panel. I can see 4 white wires bundled together terminating in a cap. I believe that if I put them to ground bars, the circuits will be live. I will consult a pro before continuing. Everything else except plumbing trim is done, so no-one can get hurt, except me.

Answer (score 2):

Stop turning on stuff, when you do not know why. They left one outlet to work with. Pulled the wires are coming back to finish. Now you have stuff on were someone can get hurt, drywallers painters all think wires are dead. And i hope the electrician knows you did this. Or you can add him to the list. Why would anyone do that i do not know.

Comment: a competent electrician would tag any breakers that should not be operated,